# Remove higlight from Ink Strokes added to InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, stroke, inkcanvas

After adding a stroke to my InkCanvas's Strokes it appears as "highlighted".
It isn't selected though, so when I tried to clear the selection it did not remove the highlight.

This is how I am adding the stroke to the InkCanvas:

```
myInkCanvas.Strokes.Add(newStroke)
```

How do I remove the highlight from the newly added stroke?

Thank you,

-Frinny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure as you have not provided much code here. Can you try this:

myInkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes.IsHighlighter = false;